# How can I do like picture?

Tags: math-mode

How can I make like first picture (for green, blue and red marks) because when I try to do I get the second picture.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWyxV.jpg [2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNpaB.jpg The thing I tried to asked on here what are the commands just for doing like the first picture marked ones? All I want is a code to that. (if it exists) The reason I ask from the picture that I don't know what is it name to search (Sorry for my English)

Comment: Which picture? I think your question misses some really important information. Also, please don't show only pictures but also the code you've used to get the second picture (once we see the second picture)!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Hope you missed to attach the image and also please do the needful to provide `MWE` as  @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz mentioned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{choices}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[choices]{itemjoin = \hfill, label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=0cm,itemindent=.5cm,labelwidth=\itemindent,labelsep=0cm,align=left}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
\lipsum[75]

\begin{choices}
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\end{choices}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I have a little problem about the gap. https://imgur.com/a/2fEorlv  how can I avoid from that? Also is there anyway to delete the left parenthesis of all options?

Comment: @Uygrr does it work now? =)

Comment: Yes it works thank you so much.